How to prove that a variable made with set tactics is equal to its value
Continuing my attempts to prove the deduction theorem in coq using the guidance, given in this question. Here is what I have so far:
Require Import List.
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality.
Import ListNotations.

(* Symbols of L theory *)
Parameter atom : Set.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Notation "-, F" := (f_not F) (at level 75, right associativity).
Notation "F ~> G" := (f_imp F G) (at level 95, right associativity).

Inductive axiom : formula -> Prop :=
  | A1: forall A B, axiom (A ~> B ~> A)
  | A2: forall A B C, axiom ( (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C) )
  | A3: forall A B, axiom ((-, B ~> -, A) ~> ((-, B ~> A) ~> B)).

Reserved Notation "Γ |-- l" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof_chain (Γ : list formula) : list formula -> Prop :=
  | pc_nil : Γ |-- []
  | pc_axiom : forall A l, axiom A -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_in : forall A l, In A Γ -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
  | pc_MP : forall A B l, In B l -> In (B ~> A) l -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l
where "Γ |-- l" := (proof_chain Γ l).

Reserved Notation "Γ |- A" (at level 98, right associativity).
Inductive proof Γ A : Prop :=
  | proof_intro : forall l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |- A
where "Γ |- A" := (proof Γ A).

Lemma proof_chain_initial : forall Γ A l, Γ |-- (A :: l) -> Γ |-- l.
Proof. intros.
(*inversion H.
- exact H3.
- exact H3.
- exact H4. *)
now dependent destruction H. Qed.

Lemma A3_proof : forall Γ l1 l2,
  Γ |-- l1 -> Γ |-- l2 -> Γ |-- (l1 ++ l2).
Proof.
 intros. induction l1.
* simpl. exact H0.
* simpl. apply proof_chain_initial in H as H1. specialize (IHl1 H1).
inversion H.
  - apply pc_axiom.
    + exact H4.
    + exact IHl1.
  - apply pc_in.
    + exact H4.
    + exact IHl1.
  - apply pc_MP with B.
    + Search _ (In ?a (?b ++ ?c)).
      apply in_or_app.
      left.
      exact H4.
    + apply in_or_app.
      left.
      exact H5.
    + exact IHl1.
Qed.


Lemma Transitivity : forall Γ A B C,
  Γ |- A ~> B ~> C -> Γ |- A ~> B -> Γ |- A ~> C.
Proof.
  intros. inversion_clear H. inversion_clear H0. set (H2 := A3_proof Γ ((A ~> B ~> C) :: l) ((A ~> B) :: l0)). specialize (H2 H1). specialize (H2 H). simpl in H2. set (Hax := (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C)). set (H3 := pc_axiom Γ Hax ((A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  assert (Hproof : axiom Hax).
  exact (A2 A B C).
  specialize (H3 Hproof H2). clear Hproof.
 (* | pc_MP : forall A B l, In B l -> In (B ~> A) l -> Γ |-- l -> Γ |-- A :: l *)
  set (H4 := pc_MP Γ ((A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C)) (A ~> B ~> C) (Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  assert (Hproof : In (A ~> B ~> C) (Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  simpl. right. left. reflexivity.
  specialize (H4 Hproof). clear Hproof.
  assert (Hproof : In ((A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> A ~> C)
         (Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0)).
  simpl. left. exact Hax.

The problem is that in Transitivity lemma I introduce a formula into the proof:
set (Hax := (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> (A ~> C)).

Which is in axiom, and I use it in Modus Ponens further. Eventually I come to this point:
Γ : list formula
A, B, C : formula
l : list formula
H1 : Γ |-- (A ~> B ~> C) :: l
l0 : list formula
H : Γ |-- (A ~> B) :: l0
H2 : Γ |-- (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0
Hax := (A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> A ~> C : formula         <-- !
H3 : Γ |-- Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0
H4 : In ((A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> A ~> C)
       (Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0) ->
     Γ |-- Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0 ->
     Γ
     |-- ((A ~> B) ~> A ~> C)
         :: Hax :: (A ~> B ~> C) :: l ++ (A ~> B) :: l0
============================
Hax = ((A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> A ~> C)

exact Hax fails with message:

The term "Hax" has type "formula" while it is expected to have type
"Hax = ((A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> A ~> C)".

rewrite Hax also fails with message:

Error: Cannot find a relation to rewrite.

This looks ridiculous. What should I do to prove that Hax = ((A ~> B ~> C) ~> (A ~> B) ~> A ~> C) when we know by definition of Hax that it is equal to this exact formula?

Doesn't reflexivity dispose of this?

You are getting confused about which tactic to use. exact Hax says to Coq that Hax proves exactly the goal, ie that the type of Hax is exactly the one displayed in the goal. But here you have to prove an equality. Luckily, this equality is trivial by unfolding the definition of Hax, and indeed the basic reflexivity tactic succeeds in proving it.
